# Habitual 'would' without any adverbs in the sentence

Tags: past-tense, adverbs

> When I was a child I **would attend** English courses for children in my home town. My character used to be quite complicated so I refused many tasks I was offered there.

Do these two sentences make sense or there's something wrong with them?

Is *would attend* a habitual usage of *would*? Or it can't be used to describe a regular action in the past without an adverb like *often*?

Comment: **in** my **home town** (two words).

Answer (score 1):

They make sense, so there is nothing wrong with them.

It certainly is a habitual usage of "would" with the meaning of "used to", and is the backshift ( the past form ) of the modal "will".

Adding the adverb "often" wouldn't make much difference expect for of course giving more emphasis to the auxiliary. You would still refer to and mean a habitual action.

Comment: The word **often** would definitely make a difference. Because it has a different meaning.

Comment: @Dhanishtha Ghosh The intended meaning'll still remain the same.

Comment: How could it be same? I mean **often** refers to a action done frequently or many times. It could have been that the person attended the courses daily or might be rarely like a once a week or so.

Comment: The usage of _often_ would then mean different things. Though it is not always required to use it. Like the OP's sentence without an adverb means slight different rather than with it.

Comment: The Habituality of the action is still expressed.

Comment: Habitability is. I never said anything related to that. I am pointing to the usage of the adverb.

Comment: Well, the adverb gives less conciseness. As I said before, more emphasis.